# Unable to Insert a Right Arrow In Android Studio Java File

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning android studio. There is a right arrow in the tutorial that I can't duplicate via keyboard or shortcuts.

The arrow is next the `fab.setOnClickListener` line #20. See screenshot below (it may be too small).

I have used the `-->` and the `=>` after view but I still get

> illegal start of expression, not a statement, ';' is
>   expected.

[image: unable to duplicate the arrow on line #20]

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the actual code.

Comment: Are you using putExtra() ?

Comment: Broke down question into paragraphs. Inserted image, minor code-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in Java 8. If you are using Android Studio 3.0 or later, it should work for you.

The name of the feature is Lambda Expressions, you should look them up and read up on them if you plan to use them.

You can use the -> combination to use them.

If your Android Studio is older than 3.0 you should update.. or use a library called retrolambda (tho you really should update)