# Java usage, not used, do not know how to find related information

Tags: java

In line 19 of the code, Callable c = () -> {

What does the symbol -> mean. How is it applied? I don't know what to call

I understand that it should be an implementation of the interface Callable method. If so, what are the benefits of this total usage?

```java
package com.example.executor;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * @author gao peng
 * @date 2019/4/18 17:56
 */
public class ExecutorserviceDemo4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    // Callable implementation
    Callable<String> c = () -> {
      System.out.println("Executed at- " + new Date());
      return "Executing task";
    };
    System.out.println("Time before execution started- " + new Date());
    // scheduling tasks with callable as param to be
    // executed after a delay of 3 Secs
    ScheduledFuture<String> sf = scheduledExecutor.schedule(c, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
      System.out.println("Value- " + sf.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    scheduledExecutor.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking in the Java Language Specification?

Comment: It's called a "lamda expression" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you very much, I saw it for the first time, I don’t know what to call.

Comment: @user207421,Yes, now I know, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is a feature introduced in Java 8. If you are using Android Studio 3.0 or later, it should work for you.

The name of the feature is Lambda Expressions, you should look them up and read up on them if you plan to use them.

You can use the -> combination to use them.

If your Android Studio is older than 3.0 you should update.. or use a library called retrolambda (tho you really should update)

I have taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47915062/9981953)

Answer (score 0):

It is called [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27).